# google place picker doesn't open (react-native ios application)

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, google-places-api, react-native

I am using Google Place Picker within a react-native iOS application.

Using the react-native native modules guide, I have exported the native module for Place Picker to be used in Javascript.

But when I call the `placePickerWithCallback` method nothing happens, no UI is shown, not even error is thrown.

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(pickPlace:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback)
{

  GMSPlacePickerConfig *config = [[GMSPlacePickerConfig alloc] initWithViewport:nil];
  GMSPlacePicker *_placePicker = [[GMSPlacePicker alloc] initWithConfig:config];

  [_placePicker pickPlaceWithCallback:^(GMSPlace *place, NSError *error) {
    if (error != nil) {
      NSLog(@"Pick Place error %@", [error localizedDescription]);
      return;
    }

    if (place != nil) {
      callback(@[[self placeToJson:place]]);
    }
  }];
}
```

I checked my API key works with sdk samples and all Google APIs are enabled.
Even one other method from Place Picker SDK- `currentPlaceWithCallback` works and returns result.

Is there some additional method I should be calling for the UI to showup when calling via react-native?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about react-native, but the problem here could be that the place picker object is locally scoped. From [the place picker docs](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/reference/interface_g_m_s_place_picker.html#a536f4f7742814fe7ca2ab135daeda34b):

> A reference to the place picker must be retained for the duration of the place picking operation. If the retain count of the place picker object becomes 0, the picking operation will be cancelled and the callback will not be invoked.

Try making the `_placePicker` variable a member variable of the class, or otherwise hold a reference to it until the operation is complete. Again, not sure how to do this in React.

Comment: Thanks, moving the `_placePicker` variable to member variable of class worked!